# Working on an RPN calculator code assignment in Java

Tags: java, class, methods

This is my second programming class and I am new to Java. I have been working on my first assignment and it involves classes and methods. I know very little about these topics and find myself lost.

My assignment asks me to create a RPN calculator that asks the user for two numbers and an operator. The calculator performs the operation on those two numbers and asks for one more number and one more operator. The calculator then uses the result from the first set and performs another operation with the new number just entered. The program ends when the user enters a letter. I am attaching my code (crude).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RPNCalc 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        double v1, v2;
        String operator = keyboard.nextLine();
        char symbol = operator.charAt(0);

        System.out.print("Enter a value v1: ");
        v1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter a value v2: ");
        v2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter one of the valid operators +, -, *, /, nCr,:  ");
        operator = keyboard.nextLine();
        switch (symbol)
            {
             case'+':
                sum.writeOutput();
                break;
             case'-':
                minus.writeOutput();
                break;
             case'*':
                times.writeOutput();
                break;
             case'/':
                divide.writeOutput();
                break;
             case'q':
                System.out.println("Your last result was "  );
             default:
                System.out.println("You must choose an appropriate operator .");
             }
    }

    double value1, value2;
    int n;

    public static double sum(double value1,double value2)
    {
        double newSum = value1 + value2;
        return newSum;
    }
    public static double minus(double value1, double value2)
    {
        double newMinus = value1 - value2;
        return newMinus;
    }
    public static double times(double value1, double value2)
    {
        double newTimes = value1 * value2;
        return newTimes;
    }
    public static double divide(double value1, double value2)
    {
        double newDivide = value1 / value2;
        return newDivide;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am receiving 4 errors stating the compiler can't find symbol. It is attached. I have no idea if I am doing this correctly and if it will give me the results I seek. Should I have created a separate java file with class description? Again, I am new to programming. RPNCalc.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
     sum.writeOutput();
     ^

Comment: What is `sum.writeOutput();`? The only `sum` I see defined is a function, and functions cannot have members, and I do not see a `writeOutput()` function defined anywhere, so that is two mistakes.

Comment: I was under the impression it was a command (method)  to produce the value of sum to the screen. Please forgive my crude programming skills, I am very new.

Comment: Given your advice on the two mistakes, I believe my code should reference newSum from the functions listed below?

Comment: Do you use any kind of IDE or do you write the code in something similar to notepad? Recommend using either Eclipse or Netbeans for your javaprojects, the development enviroment is excellent and you will learn a whole lot faster as it will point out things you are doing wrong.

Comment: I thank you for that info. My professor requires we use jGrasp. Maybe I will do both to catch up with that learning curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Here we go. I have modified your program a little bit. Here are the issues that came when modifying your program.
1. There was no "writeOutput() method in any of the classes. Therefore I had to remove that piece of code.
2. Had to introduce a while loop to make this a iterative process. 
3. moved down the operator.charAt(0) method after we read the operator string.

Since you are using switch statement, you cannot compare the operator value to "nCr" string value. To use this one, you will have to use String comparison using the equals() method.

Last but not least, the outcome of the operation should be one of the inputs for the next round of computation. Meaning the result of the first operation will be passed into the next operation's first parameter.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RPNCalc 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        double v1, v2;
//        String operator = keyboard.nextLine();
//        char symbol = operator.charAt(0);
        char operator = ' ';//First time around, set this to an something other than 'q'
        String operatorString = " ";
        System.out.print("Enter a value v1: ");
        v1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();
        while(operator != 'q')
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a value v2: ");
            v2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Enter one of the valid operators +, -, *, /, nCr,:  ");
            operatorString = keyboard.next();//nextLine() doesn't wait until the user hit enter
            operator = operatorString.charAt(0);
            switch (operator)
            {
             case'+':
                v1 = sum(v1, v2);
                System.out.println(v1);
                break;
             case'-':
                v1 = minus(v1, v2);
                System.out.println(v1);
                break;
             case'*':
                v1 = times(v1, v2);
                System.out.println(v1);
                break;
             case'/':
                v1 = divide(v1, v2);
                System.out.println(v1);
                break;
             case'q':
                System.out.println("Your last result was "  );                
             default:
                System.out.println("You must choose an appropriate operator .");
             }
        }
    }

    double value1, value2;
    int n;

    public static double sum(double value1,double value2)
    {
        double newSum = value1 + value2;
        return newSum;
    }
    public static double minus(double value1, double value2)
    {
        double newMinus = value1 - value2;
        return newMinus;
    }
    public static double times(double value1, double value2)
    {
        double newTimes = value1 * value2;
        return newTimes;
    }

    public static double divide(double value1, double value2)
    {
        if (value2 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Division by Zero. Try again");
            return value1;
        }
        double newDivide = value1 / value2;
        return newDivide;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I figured this one out with the tutor, I appreciate your help. This was very easy to understand. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You're treating your function names as if they were objects of some class. Does this even compile?

You want to exit your program when the user types 'q'.

You start off by reading an operator at the beginning. Why?

You need to encase the main body of your program in a loop.

I'll write out a few lines for you, but the bulk of the changes are left as an exercise for you

```
double result;
System.out.print("Enter the first value");
result = keyboard.nextDouble();
boolean done = false;

while (!done) {
    System.out.println("Enter a value");
    v1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter one of the valid operators +, -, *, /, nCr,:  ");
    operator = keyboard.nextLine();
    symbol = operator.charAt(0);
    switch (symbol) {
      case '+':
        result = sum(result, v1);
        break;
      ...
      case 'q':
        System.out.println("Your last result was " + result);
        done = true;
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: No the file did not compile, I received 4errors all stating RPNCalc.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
     sum.writeOutput();
     ^
  symbol:   variable sum
  location: class RPNCalc

     ^

Comment: Sorry I didn't finish my statement. I originally had a totally different program that was encased in a do while statement but was instructed to change it.